# CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL returns nil in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7

I start to test my application on iOS 7 , and I found a weird case that this code is working fine on iOS 6

```
    CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault,(CFStringRef)pdfPath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, FALSE);

    CGPDFDocumentRef myPdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url);
```

but on iOS 7 `myPdf`  is set to nil !!

I check up the `pdfPath` its exist , so any idea will be helpful guys.

Thnaks.

Comment: iOS 7 is still under NDA - you should ask this on the Apple developer forums.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy .. I already post a thread about this there.

Answer (score 2):

When an NSURL is keeping a valid URL, the output should be something like this:
file:///Users/dev/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4FF18699-D82F-4D08-88D6-44E3C11C955A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8F230041-AC15-45D3-863F-5778B565B12F/MyPDF.app/MyPDF.pdf file:///Users/dev/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4FF18699-D82F-4D08-88D6-44E3C11C955A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8F230041-AC15-45D3-863F-5778B565B12F/MyPDF.app/MyPDF.pdf

If you want to access a file through the `url`, the url should be
- a file URL prefixed with "file://"
- pointing to some place inside the app bundle

Check how you created your `url`.